# Loopback Check file attachment before upload

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

How to check in the ctx.req object that if there is a file attached or not? I am requesting a multipart form request. My custom method accepts

```
accepts: [
{ arg: 'ctx', type: 'object', http: { source:'context' } }
]
```

And in the method i want to check if there is a file attached before

```
Model.app.models.container.upload(ctx.req,ctx.result,options,function (err,fileObj){});
```

i tried to **console(ctx.req)**. But the list is huge and hard to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of effort i finally can check if there is a file attachment or not. if i send a multipart form request with the image. i can find the details of the file from fileObj.files attribute. The following code will make it clear.

```
Model.app.models.container.upload(ctx.req,ctx.result,options,function (err,fileObj){
if(err)
cb(null,err);

console.log(fileObj.files);// will give us every detail of the multi part form post request.

});
```

Comment: I want to get the attached file name in another model is it possible to get